# Dialogflow company name entity recognition

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, named-entity-recognition

I'm using Dialogflow as the NLP engine behind a chatbot, and am trying to get it to recognize company names.  In the following examples, it understands the intent well, but doesn't pick up the company name.

`Create a company called Google`

`Make a new account called Johnson & Johnson`

`New company Nike`

Does anyone have any advice on how I can get Dialogflow to start to recognize these entities? I'm wondering if there are features I don't know about, or maybe some sort of plugin/library I can utilize for this?

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what your Intents look like that are trying to use these as training phrases. Can you update your question to include a screen shot that shows the Intents? Are you saying that it isn't automatically detecting the brand name to use as a parameter, or that you're having trouble specifying where the parameter is, or that you've done this, but it still ignores it?

Comment: It isn't automatically detecting the brand name e.g. `Google` or `Facebook`.  I have given it probably about 25 training phrases like the ones I posted, and I have manually highlighted the "company name " entity, but it won't detect the company name for new examples.

Comment: Do you have an Entity Type with the brand names already defined? Again, showing us screen shots of the Intents would probably help. If you have an Entity Type, showing that as well might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no Dialogflow system entity that can do this for you as of Oct, 2020. Your best bet is to add as many training phrases as possible and create a custom entity with @sys.any as the entity type. Annotate as many training phrases as possible and let Dialogflow do the rest. When it comes to identifying company names specifically, there are two types of company names:-

1. Common company names like "Google", "Facebook" which Dialogflow can recognize without much assistance, especially if your entity type is `@sys.any`.
2. Domain-specific company names like `Overflow LLC` or `Stack and Overflow Associates`. Here, the annotated training phrases play an important role and if you have an idea of the types of companies that would need to be understood, it would help annotating those phrases (Eg: LLC, Associates, Firm etc).

Also think about how you structure your question to ensure the user enters values as per your needs. Eg: `Please type in/spell out the name of your company` increases the chances that anything your user enters would just be the company name.